# Autowiring of Service and Service Implementation class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

Following are my code

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

public EmployeeController (EmployeeService Impl empServiceImpl) {
        super();
        this.empService = empServiceImpl;

    }

}

@Service
public interface EmployeeService {

public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployeeDetails()

}

public class EmployeeServiceImpl {

public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployeeDetails(){
  //methods business logic and repo call goes here
}

}
```

When I start my server I am getting below error.

> Parameter 1 of constructor in
>   com.app.in.controller.EmployeeController required a bean of type
>   'com.app.in.service.EmployeeServiceImpl' that could not be found

My understanding might be wrong. If I annotate the EmployeeSeriveImpl class also with @Service then it working.Is that is the correct way to do it ?  My question is the service interface is annotated with @Service still why its implementation is also required to annotation. Please let me know if I miss something in that ? What is the standard method to solve this issue ?

Comment: You are missing @Component above EmployeeServiceImpl

Comment: So you meant to say that atService is requied for EmployeeService interface and atComponent is required for the Implmentation class?

Comment: You don't need to annotate the service interface.
Imagine you have 2 implementations of the same interface (This will lead to error). The only case in which I annotate interface is when defining repositories using spring data. Then I'm sure that the interface will point to single table or collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your dependency injected using a constructor. And `@Autowired` is optional in this case.

This is your example, but with a few corrections:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    // private final is a good practice. no need in @Autowire
    private final EmployeeService empService;

    // this constructor will be used to inject your dependency
    // @Autowired is optional in this case, but you can put it here
    public EmployeeController (EmployeeService empServiceImpl) {
        this.empService = empServiceImpl;

    }

}
```

I assume you have an interface `EmployeeService` and class `EmployeeServiceImpl` which implements that interface and is Spring Bean.

Something like this:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {}
```

Why this `@Service` is needed? When you put this annotation on your class, Spring knows this is a bean that Spring should manage for you (container will create an instance of it and inject it wherever it is needed).

Check Spring docs to get more details about [Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators).

The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection, as it lets you implement application components as immutable objects and ensures that required dependencies are not null.

Comment: Ok. What if I wanted to use Autowired  annotation ?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT Then you don't need a constructor : just put the annotation on the field `@Autowired private EmployeeService empService;
`

Comment: In your opienin which method is good ? I know that the constructor with parameter will help when we write test cases.

Comment: @JAVA_CAT Please check a few updates I added :) The last few sentences. I also think (the same as Spring team) that constructor-based injection is the right way to do it in most cases.

Comment: The problem with Constructor dependency is in future if I have to add more service Object then have to change the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Accepting it as the answer.

Comment: @JAVA_CAT First, your class should have single responsibility and if you have many dependencies in it - your class probably violates this principle :) Second, you are right - you will have to change the constructor, but if you are not using constructor-injection and you need to add new dependency - you will change the class anyway, right ?) You will need to add new field anyway, something like: `@Autowired MyService2 servce2`.